# Download file problems width Android 11, API 29

Tags: download, android-11

since two years I have an application width an option to download files from the webserver (href tag width php downlad and readfile() function).

Everything was working fine until Android 11. Now when you select to download a file, nothing happens.

I already has permission on Manifest fil, requestLegacyExternalStorage to true.... see example:

`<uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="28" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>`
`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true"/>`
`<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">`

The funny thing is that if I install the application directly with the debug option (Android Studio) or if I upload it to Google Play in internal test mode (internal trial), it works perfectly, but if I publish it (production) on Google Play it stops working.

Anybody run into this same problem?

I have change the manifest file, the way to upload files, and every time is the same. in debug mode o internal trial you can download the files but when you publish the app you can not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `android:maxSdkVersion="28"` from this manifest permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>
```

this will let you to save the files in your storage.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have made the change and still have the same problem. When I publish the version the file download stops working, with a silent error. As I mentioned, it is difficult to understand why it works in test mode from google developer and when it is published it stops working.

Comment: If its working in internal testing it should work in the production also. You can check once if you have declared about the permissions in the data safety. this can be a issue.

Comment: It has been solved with the android studio App Links Assistant.

It's been a while since I configured it but for some unknown reason it stopped working. As I indicate, it was still working in test mode but not in production.

Finally, I have reconfigured the links with the assistant and it seems that it has now worked correctly again. Thank you for your support.